# Difference between STRPOS(Postgres) and CHARINDEX(MSSQL) For numeric Value

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

Crate a table temp in both Postgres and SQL Server database.

```
create table temp (id numeric(10), name varchar(10));
insert into temp (id,name) values(10,'abc');
```

In MS SQL Server: `select CHARINDEX('10',id) from temp` (Success retrun 1)

In Postgres: `select strpos('10',id) from temp`

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function strpos(unknown, numeric) does not exist 
>   
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

When I pass the parameter as numeric then get an error.

In SQL Server: `select CHARINDEX(10,id) from temp;`

> SQL Error [8116] [S0001]: Argument data type int is invalid for argument 1 of charindex function.

There is a question simple that how second parameter implicitly converted to string in SQL Server, which column is numeric.

But for Postgres does not implicitly convert the value.

That's why I created a custom function but problem is same

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CHARINDEX(text, text, integer) 
   RETURNS integer 
AS $$ 
   SELECT CASE WHEN position(substr($2, $3+1)in  $1) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE position(substr($2, $3+1)in $1) + $3 END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE 
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;
```

I search lots for datatype in CHARINDEX(MSSQL).

Need help for create such type of custom function which one accept all type as String.

Comment: I tried **temp.id%TYPE** as parameter in function but when we have too many columns then for each columns I have to use to this function.

Comment: Thanks thanks, it's working!

Comment: `select strpos('10',id) from temp` The arguments should **both** be strings, and id is a numeric value, so you could cast the second argument to text, using `select strpos('10',id::text) from temp` This is all described in the fine manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Thanks for this new **strpos('10',id::text)** trick, but I got answer **function CHARINDEX(anyelement, anyelement, integer)** by @a_horse_with_no_name